# Having trouble running .class file after adding bouncycastle

Tags: java

After compiling the application with:

```
javac -cp bcprov-jdk15on-162.jar EncryptionTool.java
```

Which works successfully, when I try to run it with

```
java EncryptionTool
```

I get

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

The relevant code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Base64;


public class EncryptionTool
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        String result = Encrypt("password");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

This is all pretty much vanilla java with no graven or eclipse whatever. Just using javac to compile and java to run + notepad.

Encrypt is a method by the way, and not a class as the capitalization would imply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll also need to add your library to the class path when you run the code: `java EncryptionTool` -> `java -cp .;bcprov-jdk15on-162.jar EncryptionTool`